# jquery apply action to the specified element

Tags: javascript, jquery

anyway what i want to do is:

i have the following html:

```
<table>
    <tr id="cats">
        <td><select class="cats" id="cat_name"><option value="1">cat1</option>
                                  <option value="2">cat2</option>
            </select></td>
        <td><div id="unit"></div></td>
        <td><div id="vat"></div></td>
        <td><div id="price"></div></td>
        <td><input class="add-btn" id="Add" type="button" value="Add" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

when i click on `add` it clones the `#cats` and append it to the table ( *** all objects (tr, select, div) keep the same ids! *** )

i use this code to do that which is working fine

```
$('table').delegate(".add-btn", "click", function() {
      if(i2l < max) {
        $(this).parent().parent().after($(this).parent().parent().clone());
            // some other statments
            // don't care
      }
});
```

but the most important is that when i change `cat_name value`, `unit`, `vat`, `price` of **that catalogue** should set using ajax/jquery:

here is the jquery code

```
var prev_cat_id = ""
$('table').delegate(".cats", "change", function() {
        var cat_id = $(this).val()
        if(jQuery(this).val()){
            $.ajax({
                url: "../ajax/catalogue.json?catalogues="+jQuery(this).val(),
                datatype: "json",
                success: function(data){
                            $('#unit'+prev_cat_id).attr('id','unit' + cat_id);
                            $('#price'+prev_cat_id).attr('id','price' + cat_id);
                            $('#vat'+prev_cat_id).attr('id','vat' + cat_id);
                            $('#unit' + cat_id).text(data['unit']);
                            $('#vat' + cat_id).text(data['vat']);
                            $('#price' + cat_id).text(data['price']);
                            prev_cat_id = cat_id;
                            }
            });
        } else {
                    $('#unit'+prev_cat_id).attr('id','unit');
                    $('#price'+prev_cat_id).attr('id','price');
                    $('#vat'+prev_cat_id).attr('id','vat');
                    $('#unit').text('');
                    $('#vat').text('');
                    $('#price').text('');
                    prev_cat_id = ""
        }
    });
});
```

but the changes affects only the first row

## for example :

***info in database***

```
cat1[unit] = "dollar"
cat1[vat] = "7%"
cat1[price] = "80"


cat2[unit] = "euro"
cat2[vat] = "19%"
cat2[price] = "50"
```

**what i see in browser :**

**(1) setting `cat_name = cat1`**

```
[ cat1 [v]] euro 7% 80 [add]
```

*** (2) after adding new rows and setting `cat_name = cat2` in the second row"
only row 1 is affected ***

```
[ cat1 [v]] euro 19% 50 [add]
[ cat2 [v]]             [add]
```

***what i want is exactly this***

```
[ cat1 [v]] euro 7%  80 [add]
[ cat2 [v]] euro 19% 50 [add]
[      [v]]             [add]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ID's is certainly easiest selector to write, however when working with multiple instances of a module it is often more complicated than using traverses to find common class names of elements.

For starters will demonstrate how to use `closest()` and `find()` to isolate row instance. Note that I changed all the element ID's to class

```
/* store empty row for adding later*/
var $rowClone=$('#cats').clone().removeAttr('id');


/* if using jQuery >1.6 should use on() rather than delegate*/
$('table').delegate(".add-btn", "click", function() {    
          var $currentRow=  $(this).closest('tr');
        $currentRow.after($rowClone.clone());         

});

$('table').delegate(".cats", "change", function() {
    var val=$(this).val();  
    /* define current row to use in AJAX success*/  
    var $row= $(this).closest('tr');
    if( val){
        $.ajax({
            url:'/echo/json/',/* jsfiddle demo ajax url*/
            type:'post',
            data: {json:dummyData( val)},/* jsfiddle demo data generation*/
             datatype: "json",
             success: function(data){
                 /* only look within $row for elements to update*/
                 $row.find('.unit').text( data.unit);
                 $row.find('.vat').text( data.vat);
                 $row.find('.price').text( data.price);
             }
        })
    }
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/r8vKb/2/

This will help you resolve the UI problems. As for DB issues, somewhere within this code you likely need some row ID's that would match with your db setup. Would need to understand your data structure a bit better to help with that